# angular material decrease all typography levels font-size

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, material-design, typography

Using Persian font-family called "iransans" (tall font), all elements look larger than usual with standard font-size.

I use [custom typography](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography) in  styles.scss to **decrease font-size** by 2px, hence keeping *line-height* and *weight* untouched:

```
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: "iransans",
  $title: mat-typography-level(18px, 20px, 500), // default font-size was 20px as I inspected
  $button: mat-typography-level(12px, 24px, 500), // default  font-size was 14px as I inspected
  // other levels
);

@include mat-core($custom-typography);
```

The problem is I need to find default font-size, line-height and weight of all [13 levels of typographies](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography) and decrease their font-size by 2px as above.

First of all, do I follow correct approach for decreasing font-size?

**If yes**, How can I get defaults of all typography levels, decrease font-size and set them to my custom typography?

**If no**, what is the correct shorthand to achieve this without dealing with defaults?

Comment: Look at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/core/typography/_typography.scss#L26) and yes your approach is correct.

Comment: @OscarLudick Thanks for confirming. Althought I found the defaults by debugging